# Kasa HS210 wiring setup

Tags: lighting, smart-switch

Switch-1 has one black, one white and one red and green neutral connected to the switch

Switch-2 has two cables coming into the box. The red and and white wires coming from the cables are connected to the switch. The black wires from each cable are connected via wirenut.

Switch-3 has one black, one white and one red and green neutral connected to the switch

I have one HS210. Which switch should I replace with the HS210 and how should it be wired?

Comment: Is this a 4-way switch set up where all 3 switches control the same set of lights? Pictures of the wiring at all the switches would help immeasurably (show the wires connected to the switches and how they leave the box. Also "green neutral" is NOT a thing. Green/bare/Green-Yellow are ground. Of all the different wire color standards, that one's consistent pretty much world wide.

Comment: Which country? "Red and green neutral" is definitely not US.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?